# Unusual date processing with library lubridate in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I am using R to process dates and working on a simple task. My goal is to use the current date and check the date after 6 months. Below I am pasting a snippet of the code that is producing different responses to dates. All help is appreciated.

```
library(lubridate)
first <- as.Date('2004-05-31')
class(first)
# [1] "Date"
first_next_6M <- first
month(first_next_6M) <- month(first_next_6M) + 6
first_next_6M
# [1] NA

second <- as.Date('2010-05-01')
second_next_6M <- second
class(second)
# [1] "Date"
month(second_next_6M) <- month(second_next_6M) + 6
second_next_6M
# [1] "2010-11-01"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using lubridate and want to get a date 6 months from the current date, you should use

```
first %m+% months(6)
```

If you just add 6 to the month value of `2004-05-31` you get `2004-11-31` and November only has 30 days not 31 so you can't just do arithmetic on the month

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks